# Disabling one button by enabling the other and vice versa

Tags: java, button, swt

I would like to be able to disable button B, when I click on button A (and the opposite too).

My problem is, that once button A enabled, button B is disabled (that's okay) BUT when I disable button A, button B keeps disabled.

How could I solve that?

Here an example I made to help understand the problem :

```
package test;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.wb.swt.SWTResourceManager;

public class Buttons 
{
    protected static Shell shell;

    protected static void createContents() 
    {
       // Creation of the window
       shell = new Shell();
       shell.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
       shell.setSize(800, 600);
       shell.setText("Test");
       shell.setLayout(null);

       // Creation of the background canvas
       Canvas area1 = new Canvas(shell, SWT.NONE);
       area1.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
       area1.setBounds(82, 119, 597, 393);
       buttons(area1);
    }
    public static void buttons(Canvas area1)
    {
       // Creation of the canvas to color the text area from the buttons
       Canvas case1 = new Canvas(area1, SWT.NONE);

       // Creation of the buttons
       final Button buttonA = new Button(case1, SWT.CHECK);
       final Button buttonB = new Button(case1, SWT.CHECK);

       // Position of the first button
       case1.setBounds(84, 111, 136, 64);
       buttonA.setBounds(10, 10, 147, 16);
       buttonA.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() 
       {
           @Override
           public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) 
            {
               boolean chkRpmFilter = buttonA.getSelection();
               buttonB.setEnabled(false);
               System.out.println("Button A clicked state is " +chkRpmFilter);
            }
        });
       buttonB.setEnabled(true);
       buttonA.setText("Button A");

       // Position of the second button
       buttonB.setBounds(10, 32, 123, 16);
       buttonB.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() 
       {
             @Override
             public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) 
             {
                boolean sWinddirections = buttonB.getSelection();
                buttonA.setEnabled(false);
                System.out.println("Button B clicked state is " +sWinddirections);
              }
       });
       buttonA.setEnabled(true);
       buttonB.setText("Button B");
       }
       public static void main(String[] args) 
       {
         Display display = Display.getDefault();
         createContents();
         shell.open();
         shell.layout();
         while (!shell.isDisposed()) 
         {
           if (!display.readAndDispatch()) 
              {
                display.sleep();
               }
          }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `getSelection()` to know if the buttonA is check or not to re-enable the second button.

```
   buttonA.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() 
   {
       @Override
       public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) 
        {
           boolean chkRpmFilter = buttonA.getSelection();
           buttonB.setEnabled(!buttonA.getSelection());
           System.out.println("Button A clicked state is " +chkRpmFilter);
        }
    });
```

Comment: how could i not get this ><
Thanks a lot, it works just fine !

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final Button a = new Button(shell, SWT.TOGGLE);
    a.setText("a");
    final Button b = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    b.setText("b");

    a.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
        {
            b.setEnabled(!a.getSelection());
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Just call `setEnabled()` on `b` with `!getSelection()` of `a`.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.wb.swt.SWTResourceManager;

public class Buttons {
    protected static Shell shell;

    protected static void createContents() {
        // Creation of the window
        shell = new Shell();
        shell.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
        shell.setSize(800, 600);
        shell.setText("Test");
        shell.setLayout(null);

        // Creation of the background canvas
        Canvas area1 = new Canvas(shell, SWT.NONE);
        area1.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
        area1.setBounds(82, 119, 597, 393);
        buttons(area1);
    }

    public static void buttons(Canvas area1) {
        // Creation of the canvas to color the text area from the buttons
        Canvas case1 = new Canvas(area1, SWT.NONE);
        case1.setBounds(84, 111, 136, 64);

        // Creation of the buttons
        final Button buttonA = new Button(case1, SWT.CHECK);

        // Position of the first button
        buttonA.setBounds(10, 10, 147, 16);
        buttonA.setEnabled(true);
        buttonA.setSelection(false);
        buttonA.setText("Button A");

        final Button buttonB = new Button(case1, SWT.CHECK);

        // Position of the second button
        buttonB.setBounds(10, 32, 123, 16);
        buttonB.setEnabled(true);
        buttonB.setSelection(false);
        buttonB.setText("Button B");

        buttonA.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
                boolean chkRpmFilter = buttonA.getSelection();
                buttonB.setEnabled(!chkRpmFilter);
                System.out.println("Button A clicked state is " + chkRpmFilter);
            }
        });

        buttonB.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
                boolean sWinddirections = buttonB.getSelection();
                buttonA.setEnabled(!sWinddirections);
                System.out.println("Button B clicked state is "
                        + sWinddirections);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        createContents();
        shell.open();
        shell.layout();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please clarify your question. Do you mean by enabling/ disabling of buttons (checkboxes as per your code) or check/uncheck.

> My problem is, that once button A enabled, button B is disabled
>   (that's okey) BUT when i disable button A, button B keeps disabled.

How could you say you disable button A in above statement since Button B is already disabled, and the requirement is clicking on Button B should disable button A. Its a deadlock

Comment: the thing is i want to disable button b on clicking on button a.
But when i click again on button a, button b keeps disabled.

Comment: So you want to enable button B again when you click second time on Button A ?

Comment: @user2842558 This is not an answer but a comment. Please post it as such. If you don't have enough reputation, build up more reputation first by giving actual answers.

Comment: @user2842558 Yup, that's it :)

Comment: @Baz Thanks Baz for showing of your reputation. The only reason for asking counter question here to th OP is to understand his requirement before giving the solution. By the way pls could you explain how your answer above answers the question. The requirement was "I would like to be able to disable button B, when i click on button A (and the opposite too)."

Comment: @user2842558 It answers the question, because it does exactly what the OP was asking for.

Comment: @user2842558 Feel free to report my comment to the moderators if you think that I was treating you unjustly.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why are you doing this but can't you use a Toggle button: `SWT.TOGGLE`

Comment: I am using this, because i have many buttons, but i can use some with others, but others not.
Let me give you a simple example : 
I have 3 buttons, A, B and C.
A can be used with B.
A can be used with C.
B can be used with A
But B can not be used with C.
So when B is selected, i want C to be disabled.

Comment: Are these button has actions or are they to "select a preference". If when B selected all it does is disabling C, you can use two groups of radio buttons or toggle buttons: Group1=A, Group2=B,C.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use the mediator pattern
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

//Colleague interface
interface Command {
    void execute();
}

//Abstract Mediator
interface IMediator {
    public void book();
    public void view();
    public void search();
    public void registerView(BtnView v);
    public void registerSearch(BtnSearch s);
    public void registerBook(BtnBook b);
    public void registerDisplay(LblDisplay d);
}

//Concrete mediator
class Mediator implements IMediator {

    BtnView btnView;
    BtnSearch btnSearch;
    BtnBook btnBook;
    LblDisplay show;

    //....
    public void registerView(BtnView v) {
        btnView = v;
    }

    public void registerSearch(BtnSearch s) {
        btnSearch = s;
    }

    public void registerBook(BtnBook b) {
        btnBook = b;
    }

    public void registerDisplay(LblDisplay d) {
        show = d;
    }

    public void book() {
        btnBook.setEnabled(false);
        btnView.setEnabled(true);
        btnSearch.setEnabled(true);
        show.setText("booking...");
    }

    public void view() {
        btnView.setEnabled(false);
        btnSearch.setEnabled(true);
        btnBook.setEnabled(true);
        show.setText("viewing...");
    }

    public void search() {
        btnSearch.setEnabled(false);
        btnView.setEnabled(true);
        btnBook.setEnabled(true);
        show.setText("searching...");
    }

}

//A concrete colleague
class BtnView extends JButton implements Command {

    IMediator med;

    BtnView(ActionListener al, IMediator m) {
        super("View");
        addActionListener(al);
        med = m;
        med.registerView(this);
    }

    public void execute() {
        med.view();
    }

}

//A concrete colleague
class BtnSearch extends JButton implements Command {

    IMediator med;

    BtnSearch(ActionListener al, IMediator m) {
        super("Search");
        addActionListener(al);
        med = m;
        med.registerSearch(this);
    }

    public void execute() {
        med.search();
    }

}

//A concrete colleague
class BtnBook extends JButton implements Command {

    IMediator med;

    BtnBook(ActionListener al, IMediator m) {
        super("Book");
        addActionListener(al);
        med = m;
        med.registerBook(this);
    }

    public void execute() {
        med.book();
    }

}

class LblDisplay extends JLabel {

    IMediator med;

    LblDisplay(IMediator m) {
        super("Just start...");
        med = m;
        med.registerDisplay(this);
        setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 24));
    }

}

class MediatorDemo extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    IMediator med = new Mediator();

    MediatorDemo() {
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(new BtnView(this, med));
        p.add(new BtnBook(this, med));
        p.add(new BtnSearch(this, med));
        getContentPane().add(new LblDisplay(med), "North");
        getContentPane().add(p, "South");
        setSize(400, 200);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        Command comd = (Command) ae.getSource();
        comd.execute();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MediatorDemo();
    }

}
```

Comment: First of all, this problem can be solved with 5 lines of code. Second, the question is asking for SWT code, not Swing/AWT...